# Is the property reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, transitive, equivalence relation, partially ordered given the relation below?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, relations, equivalence-relations

I'm working on this and I'm supposed to figure out if the following properties apply to the below relations.

Properties are:

```
1. Reflexive
2. Symmetric
3. Anti-Symmetric
4. Transitive
5. Equivalence Relation
6. Partially Ordered Set
```

Relation:

> 1. The relation $R$ on the set of all real function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ where $f \ R \ g$ if and only if  $f(n) = O(g(n))$
> 2. The relation $R$ on the set of all real function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ where $f \ R \ g$ if and only if  $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$

My work so far:

For first relation:

> a. YES:
>
> b. NO:
>
> c. NO:
>
> d. YES:
>
> e. NO:
>
> f. NO:

For second relation

> a.YES:
>
> b.YES:
>
> c.NO:
>
> d.YES:
>
> e.YES:
>
> f.NO:

Am I doing this right? Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If I were correcting your (presumably) homework, I would want more details on your reasoning for transitivity, in both cases. Nevertheless, all your answers are correct. Good job.